# Scala initialization behaviour

Tags: scala, initialization, traits

Please look at the following code.

```
trait MyTrait { val myVal : String }

class MyClass extends MyTrait { val myVal = "Value" }

class MyClass2(val myVal: String) extends MyTrait
```

Why does the initialization order differ in case of `MyClass` and `MyClass2`?
The constructor of `MyClass` will be as

```
MyClass() {
  MyTrait$class.$init$(this);
  myVal = value
}
```

The constructor of `MyClass2` will be

```
MyClass2(String myVal) { this.myVal = myVal; MyTrait$class.$init$(this) }
```

I think the initialization order should be as `MyClass2`'s constructor does, the same for both cases.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At the end of section 5.1 of the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), the following is defined:

> **Template Evaluation.** Consider a template *sc **with** mt 1 **with** mt
>   n {stats}*. If this is the template of
>   a trait (§5.3.3) then its
>   mixin-evaluation consists of an eval-
>   uation of the statement sequence
>   stats. If this is not a template of a
>   trait, then its evaluation consists of
>   the following steps.
>
> - First, the superclass constructor sc is evaluated (§5.1.1).
> - Then, all base classes in the template’s linearization (§5.1.2) up
>     to the template’s superclass denoted
>     by sc are mixin-evaluated.
>     Mixin-evaluation hap- pens in reverse
>     order of occurrence in the
>     linearization.
> - Finally the statement sequence stats is evaluated.

Note, however, that the constructor parameters may be used by any constructors that follow it. Therefore, it needs to be initialized before them. This is made explicit at the end of section 5.1.1:

> An evaluation of a constructor
>   invocation *x.c targs. .
>   .(argsn)* consists of the following
>   steps:
>
> - First, the prefix *x* is evaluated.
> - Then, the arguments *args1 , . . . , argsn* are evaluated from left to
>     right.
> - Finally, the class being constructed is initialized by evaluating the
>     template of the class referred to by
>     *c*.

This you don't have any problem with, but you do have a problem with *{stats}* being executed last. The reason why *{stats}* is executed last is that it may reference attributes of its ancestor classes and traits, whereas the ancestors obviously have no knowledge about its descendants. Therefore, the ancestors need to be fully initialized before *{stats}* gets executed.

Of course, it is possible that you *do* need early initialization. This is covered by section 5.1.6: Early Definitions. Here's how you'd write it:

```
class MyClass extends { val myVal = "Value" } with MyTrait
```

Comment: Eventually I've seen the reason why Scala initializes an object in that order. Thanks for the answer, Daniel.