# Getting command-line arguments in Scala traits

Tags: scala

I've got a large number of simple command-line Scala apps which share quite a bit of common structure.  All of them inherit from scala.App, which is just fine.   I would like to refactor out the shared structure of these command-line Apps into a common trait, which I could then inherit into my (much simpler) command-line app classes.  The problem arises in that some of the common structure includes parsing of command-line arguments.

```
object MyScript extends BaseScript with App{
   //small bits of business logic using components defined in BaseScript
}

trait BaseScript extends App{
    val configuration = loadConfiguration(args(0))
    //setup a bezillion components, usable from any of the scripts, based on the configuration
}
```

This compiles, but fails with an NPE when it comes time to actually dereference `args`, presumably because the `App` trait hasn't yet been initialized.  Changing trait orders and changing the inheritance of App in BaseScript to be a self-type declaration do nothing, as have experiments with DelayedInit.  Declaring the components as "lazy" in BaseScript would work, but I also wish need to actually use those components during initialization (e.g., setting up log directories and loading JDBC driver classes based on the configuration), so the benefits of laziness are lost.  Is there something I can do to get the command-line arguments visible and initialized in the BaseScript trait?

Comment: Not much I can add other than to check out scopts: https://github.com/jstrachan/scopt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet is to change your `BaseScript` trait into a class for two reasons. The first is that **compared with classes, trait initializations are executed in reverse order**. See [this question on initialization behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830332/scala-initialization-behaviour). Second, `BaseScript` semantically is more of a superclass than additional behavior. I think you will find that this can simplify things.

When executing `MyScript`, the following code initializes the `BaseScript` class first. `BaseScript` is dependent on the `App` trait in turn and forces it to initialize first.

```
object MyScript extends BaseScript {
  //small bits of business logic using components defined in BaseScript
  println( "running" )
  println( "arg(0): " + configuration )
}

class BaseScript extends App {
  val configuration = loadConfiguration(args)
  //setup a bezillion components, usable from any of the scripts, based on the configuration
  def loadConfiguration( args: Array[String] ) = {
    println( "configuring" )
    if ( args.length > 0 ) args(0) else null
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that still doesn't get the App initialization to occur after the BaseScript initialization, so the call to "args" still NPEs.  Crud.

Comment: I've provided some code that seems to work for myself. Without seeing all of your cases I may be missing something however removing the "with App" mix in whenever you extend BaseScript may resolve things.

Comment: That did it.  Having "with App" on MyScript is what screwed things up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using lazy val (and not extending the `App` trait)?

```
trait BaseScript { self : App =>
  lazy val configuration = loadConfiguration(args(0))
  //setup a bezillion components, usable from any of the scripts
  //based on the configuration
}
```

Comment: Edited the initial question to explain why that sadly won't work for me either

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `App` [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/App.scala) it seems you can override `main` to do things with args before your app code runs:

```
trait AppUtil extends App {
  def myInit(args: Array[String]) {
    println("args " + args.size)
  }
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    myInit(args)
    super.main(args)
  }
}
```

I suspect the `App` source can give you inspiration to rewrite your own customized `App`. The code is really not that long and you'll have more control on things, such as what you do with `args`, what happens before and after your run `main`.

Comment: I tried this and got deprecation warning:
"overriding method main in trait App is deprecated: main should     not be overridden"

Comment: It's been 5 years, I'm sure my answer is obsolete.

Comment: I found that you can just use args in your code, without any main function in the class extending App. Without having args explicitly defined in your code. I just used val numSegments = args(0).toInt in my case, and used the value passed from command line.